# set culture of individual WPF user control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, culture

I have written a user control which is not compatible with cultures other than "en-US". Also it is inevitable to embed this user control in an application with a culture which is not "en-US". So is it possible to force the application to not to change this user control's culture?

Its preferable to have a solution inside the user control.

I have read this thread :
[Localizing a WinForms Application with Embedded WPF User Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374518/localizing-a-winforms-application-with-embedded-wpf-user-controls)
but I can not use **WpfLocalization.LocalizationScope.SetCulture** 
Does this function really exists ?

And also there is a **Localizable** tag which can be set to **False** but It is just for resource definitions in **.csproj** files:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

So is there anybody who has any idea about this problem ?

---

**More clarification :**
 Suppose we have an application with culture X and a user control which is compatible with culture "en-US". This user control has a dependency property which is of DateTime type and it is getting its value by this way :

```
<my:uc1 x:Name="UserControl1" Date="4234/12/22" />
```

When application culture is "en-US" user control will get **"4234/12/22"** but when the application culture is something else, it converts **"4234/12/22"** automatically to the application's own calendar and delivers **"0744/04/08"** to the user control and ruins every logic behind the user control ! It's completely a disaster.

I want to prevent this conversion by setting the user control's culture exclusively to "en-US".

Hope that I have clarified the situation enough.

Comment: Besides the surprising date you want to use (which by the way isn't represented in "en-US" format which is `M/d/yyyy`) which culture converts it to "0744/04/08" (even more surprising)?

Comment: @Martin Liversage: It's just an example. Let me keep that culture clandestine :-&

Comment: Sorry if I disclose any secret, but given the huge year I'd say Hebraic calendar... More seriously, this thread is really interesting  to me as I'll probably have to manage soon dual-culture (French/Arabic language or Gregorian/Ethiopian calendar) oddities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the [`FrameworkElement.Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.language.aspx) property of your control or apply the `xml:lang` attribute to the XAML of your control. The value you have to set is `en-US`.

The culture you set using this property/attribute affects how culture-specific strings are converted in the control. E.g. if you display a `DateTime` using the `D` (long date) format you get something like `Monday, 30 April 2012` when `xml:lang="en-US"` and `30. april 2012` when `xml:lang="da-DK"`.

However, if you specify a date in XAML like in

```
<my:uc1 x:Name="UserControl1" Date="4/30/2012" />
```

that date is parsed using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (basically `en-US`). That is not the behavior you seem to describe. You are a bit vague in the description of you real problem but to verify my claim you can try to enter `30/4/2012` for the date and see that it fails to compile. It does that not only when the current culture of Visual Studio is `en-US` but also as it is in my case `da-DK` (where the date format is `d/M/yyyy`).

Comment: Thanks for your consideration but it doesn't affect the user control culture which is still non "en-US". I have checked culture in user control load but it is still the same as past.

Comment: @SarahCompard: Can you clarify the meaning of _user control culture_ in your comment? If you set the `xml:lang` attribute in XAML then string formatting in bindings will use the appropriate `CultureInfo` etc. Where exactly in your user control are you having localization problems?

Comment: I have provided more details in the question. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Thank you very very much. The point was in CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. I didn't know anything about it. I temporary set thread culture to it and do my job then return back the culture to its previous culture. It was impossible with other cultures. You finished my nightmares which was lasted for fortnight!!!

Comment: I've set all these to my hr-HR and controls still format numbers in en-US. These same settings work in another project: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture ;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture ;
             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
             CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
             System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentCulture ;